# How to seperate the genus into different group based on th ANI calculation?

Tags: phylogenetics, phylogeny

I've calculated the ANI of the streptomyces genus, but I'm confused about how to separate them into a different group, could anybody kindly tell me how to do that? Thanks!!!

Comment: Oh thats easy you use clustering analysis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANI = average nucleotide identity.

This will give you a 2x2 matrix. You reconstruct a phylogeny using clustering, the most important being neighbor-joining, UPGMA is very occassionally used.

The statistic is clustering algorithm and its done by pairwise reconstruction of sister groups. Once a sister-group is defined (usually on nearest-neighor both in neighbor-joining and UPGMA) the genetic divergence from the hypothetical node is established either using the mean (UPGMA) or additive criteria (neighbor-joining). Okay enough theory ...

You get Mega X and find out the import format for a 2x2 distance matric. Mega X however will calculate this for you. You then go to the build tree menu heading and click "neighbor-joining" (or "distance"). The tree will very quickly automatically appear.

Comment: Thanks~ Wish you have a good day (or night???)  : )

Comment: But isn't the result of ANI is an NxN matrix? How to translate it into a 2x2 matrix? I used the dcast() funtion in R to transform the data, from A to B.
A:
Streptomyces_zinciresistens.fna Streptomyces_aidingensis.fna    78.6608 909     2493
Streptomyces_zinciresistens.fna Streptomyces_gilvigriseus.fna   78.4136 719     2493
...
B:
                Kitasatospora.papulosa Streptomyces.achromogenes Streptomyces.adustus
Kitasatospora papulosa                  100.0000                   81.0354              81.1125

Comment: Okay, first up I don't use R, I use Python instead, the only thing I'll use R for is ggplot2. I've never worked on Strep. What we should do is arrange a time to chat on the phylogenetics debugging forum

Comment: Sorry, but where is the phylogenetics debugging forum? ... I come from a web restricted area, have little knowledge about the foreign web... CRY

Comment: Thank you!!! You are so nice !!!

Comment: ??? Where is the invitation? Should I check my Gmail message box? I can't see it in stack exchange's message box

Comment: Hi @Tangli83 really sorry I was late, if you are around the same time tomorrow please let me know

Comment: Yes, I'll be around at the same time tomorrow, it's ok.

Comment: Just a minute I'm in a meeting

Comment: okkk, it'll be fine, i'll memorize the words(or recite words)